# Passing Int between Xamarin.Form pages C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to pass an Integer from Questions.xaml to Result.xaml.
It should be really simple but i have not found the correct answer in my case yet.

I have tried it Passing Data through a Page Constructor but this is one of the errors i'm receiving:

[image]

Here is my structure:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: please do NOT post code as images

Answer (score 1):

in `Question`, when you are ready to navigate to the next page

```
// data is the data you want to pass
// Question should already be contained in a NavigationPage
Navigation.PushAsync(new Result(data));
```

to retrieve the data in Result

```
public void Result(string data)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   MyLabel.Text = data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In this case how would i retrieve this data in for example a label?

Comment: see my edit - Xamarin has great docs and numerous sample apps that demonstrate these concepts, you should take the time to look at them